# How does discord's api get live data

Tags: python, websocket, discord

I am wondering how apis like discord.py get live data. Other than putting a request.get in a while True loop I am wondering how live data can be retrieved like a push server. Is there some magic in using a discord bot that allows us to receive push information or can it be done via requests or some custom websocket?

Answer (score -1):

You can look more into Event-driven architecture.

A simple API can use something like PubSub (Publisher-Subscriber) model to subscribe to updates pushed by the server, and the server maintains a list of subscribers to notify. In essence its a format of an open websocket connection or a http connection which is kept alive. More specifically its implemented through something called "Server-Sent Events" (SSE).

https://flask-sse.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events

Discord.py works on something like that. in fact for Discord.js, the code looks exactly the same as connecting to a server through a websocket (e.g. `client.on("event", callback())` which means whenever the client receives a notification of "event" happening, it will execute the "callback" function.)

Hope I've given you an idea of how real-time updates would work in an application.